# What advantages does Trinity have over Geth or Parity? What differences does it have?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, python, py-evm, trinity

With the exception of the language it is being written in, what are the main differences that [Trinity](https://trinity.ethereum.org/) has over Geth or Parity (if any). What advantages does it have? Disadvantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to note that `trinity` is in alpha, and will not be production-ready for some time. I expect that to be a deal-breaker for anything that has to be in production in say, the next year. So the following is *aspirational*.

A key goal for `trinity` is comprehension for humans. That should make it an ideal tool for:

- People new to the EVM to understand how it all works in practice
- Researchers to prototype new ideas in a production-viable node
- Standards authors to write a reference implementation for EIPs
- Tinkerers to write their own plugins to add home-grown functionality

It will never be as fast as go/rust implementations. Which means it is not a good tool for:

- Proof of Work mining
- Low-end hardware

Comment: Thank you @carver. It is always nice to get an answer straight from the source. Everything you said makes sense.